# PHP Laravel, при получении данных из формы возвращается NULL

Tags: php, laravel

Есть два контроллера, первый выводит страничку для выбора файла:

```
public function select(){
    return view('select');
}
```

Выводит он следующую страничку:

```
@section('content')
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'image.upload']) !!}
<div class="col-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <br>
        {{ Form::file('image') }}
        @csrf
        <br>
        {{ Form::submit("Установить картинку", ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) }}
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

Второй контроллер её получает и выводит.

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $image = $request->file('image');
    return var_dump($image);
}
```

И выводит он в любом случае NULL. 
Почему это происходит, и как это исправить?

P.S. для создания форм юзаю Laravel Collective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы передать файлы в форме надо указать:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

В данном случае:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true)) }}
    //
{{ Form::close() }}
```

https://webzone.kz/publication/php-uploading-file-to-server

Answer (score 0):

А зачем return var_dump($image);? 
Просто return $image;
А после какой нибудь переменной присваиваешь эту функцию, и затем переменную var_dump